# Python walking through directory

Tags: python, io, os.walk

I'm trying to open many text files into a specific directory in order to process the text with NLP functions. My code is:

```
path= r'c:\my\directory'    

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith(".txt"):
            absolute_filename = os.path.join(root, filename)
            with open(absolute_filename, 'r') as f:
                content= f.read()
                ... processing code
```

The problem is that the above code open only the first 20 files, when it arrive to certan file it give me the following error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\my\\directory\\Andrej Aleksandrovic Mironov.txt'
```

I already wrote a question for the same problem and what I got is the code above.
Can somebody help me?

Comment: Debug it. Print value of files before nested for to verify that file does exist.

Comment: Does that file exist on your disk ? Can you open it in a text editor (notepad) ? Also I think path should be like this `path = 'C:\your\directory'`

Comment: Yes the file exist and i can edit it...

Comment: Can you change the path like in my previous comment and try again ? Can you print `absolute_filename` and show one that worked and one that did not ?

Comment: The first 20 files that it's reading successfully, do they have spaces in the filename like this one? `Andrej Aleksandrovic Mironov.txt`?

Comment: The files have different kinds of names, even numbers.

Comment: Anyway Saksow! I can print the absolute_filename only if i use "  path= r'C:\my\directory'  "and it give me even the name of the file i get in the error. es. C:\Users\Cosimo\Desktop\Tirocinio\progetto_arianna\Sintesi H2O_txt\sintesi_txt\1000testi\Andrej Aleksandrovic Mironov.txt

Comment: Are you able to open it outisde the script?: `with open('C:\Users\Cosimo\Desktop\Tirocinio\progetto_arianna\Sintesi H2O_txt\sintesi_txt\1000testi\Andrej Aleksandrovic Mironov.txt') as f:    f.read()`

Comment: I don't! I can't open that specific file in that way.

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys I solved the problem. I used the same code I posted but I changed the name of all files in my directory. I give them the same name and after I runned the code. It works, but I still don't understand why I couldn't open the files while they were keeping differents names.