# NoneType object is not callable python

Tags: python, typeerror, nonetype

I have been encountering an error message which reads, 'TypeError: NoneType object is not callable'. This is similar to a previous question I had, but the answer to my question gave me an error, or maybe I just didn't read the answer properly.

Image files (code causing the error message is `for _, __, img_files in os.chdir(path):`)

```
def import_folder(path):
    surface_list = []

    for _, __,img_files in os.chdir(path):
        for image in img_files:
            full_path = path + '/' + image
            image_surf = pygame.image.load(full_path).convert_alpha()
            surface_list.append(image_surf)
```

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\Thing.py", line 13, in <module>
level = Level(level_0, window)
File "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\level2.py", line 32, in __init__
self.coin_sprites = self.create_tile_group(coins_layout, 'coins')
File "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\level2.py", line 61, in create_tile_group
sprite = Coin(tile_size, x, y, (x, y), 
'C:\\Users\\daniel\\Desktop\\game\\coins\\gold')
File "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\tiles2.py", line 46, in __init__
super().__init__(size, x, y, pos, path)
File "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\tiles2.py", line 28, in __init__
self.frames = import_folder(path)
File "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\support2.py", line 10, in import_folder
for _, __,img_files in os.chdir(path):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

os I'm importing:

```
import os
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

Comment: `os.chdir` is a function that changes the state of the environment. It is not actually returning anything. I'm not sure what the plan is exactly here but I think you are mistaking `os.chdir` for `os.walk` or even you intent to use `os.listdir`

Comment: @MYousefi That seems to be the mistake, but it shouldn't be causing this error.

Comment: This would happen if you did `os.chdir = None` earlier in the program.

Comment: @MYousefi ITYM `os.path.walk`

Comment: The `in` operator is attempting to iterate on the object resulting from `os.chdir`. This object is `None`

Comment: @Daniel You can look at [Walking Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41260524/python-walking-through-directory) questions and guides online for more information.

Comment: ok, I fixed that bug but now theres another one D:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[os.chdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chdir) changes the working directory to the path and returns None. You're getting the error because you're trying to iterate on this None.

You probably meant to use [os.listdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir)

Edit: [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) fits your if condition better so that may be preferable.

Comment: now it says 'too many values (expected 3)'

Comment: As the documentation says, os.listdir just returns a list of paths. But you're expecting three things in your if condition (_, __, and img_files). If you want to use this form, the function you want is [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk). Look at the example there to see how to use it.